# Not able to set password in ArchLinux

Tags: password, useradd

I logged in as root and created a new account:

```
# useradd -d /home/onie -m onie
# su onie
```

Now I try to set the password for `onie` myself using the `passwd` command, but it's asking for my current password when I don't have one!

Comment: It seems that only root can change the password for the new user.

Comment: You might want to use the interactive option, `adduser`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't specify a password when running `useradd` (`-p PASSWORD`), it disables the password on that account; the only way to login to it is through some other authentication method (e.g. SSH keys), or by `su`ing from root. Since passwords are disabled, you can't set a new one as a regular user. Root can change anyone's password without needing the current password though, so run:

```
[root@myhost ~]# passwd onie
```